# Preserving File Permissions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, file-permissions, access-control

I have a file that is often deleted and recreated (I have no control over this behavior). However when the file is recreated, it doesn't retain the permissions that it  had before it was deleted. So I wrote this code to try to fix that problem:

```
var access = File.GetAccessControl(filepath, AccessControlSections.Access);
deleteAndRecreate(filepath);
File.SetAccessControl(filepath, access);
```

But this doesn't work. If I explicitly give "TestUser" read permission for the file, then after I run this code, TestUser will no longer have read permissions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you do something other than delete the file... like empty it out instead?  What is the non-existence of the file doing that an empty file couldn't accomplish?

Comment: Have you tried to create your file under a directory with your pre-set permissions?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN I would totally do that, but as I said, I have no control over the behavior. It's a 3rd party library problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand enough to answer this question, but I suppose that you can't assign the same instance of a FileSecurity object to a file other than the one from which you got it.  Perhaps you can figure this out by reading the ACL Technology Overview at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229742.aspx

Comment: If you can, you might be better off setting the permissions (once) on the parent folder, so that whenever the file is created, it inherits the correct permissions from its parent folder by default.

Comment: @JoeWhite I agree. That's actually what I was doing, but the library I was using (somehow, for some reason) would create a file that didn't inherit permissions from the parent folder. I have since updated to the latest version of the library and it doesn't have this problem. But for future reference I'm still curious to see a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the second parameter

```
var access = File.GetAccessControl(filepath); 
deleteAndRecreate(filepath); 
File.SetAccessControl(filepath, access);
```

Comment: And this executes with no exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the `FileSecurity` object returned by `GetAccessControl` is no longer valid once the file is deleted.

Have you tried something like this instead (untested)?

```
deleteAndRecreate(filepath);
FileSecurity access = File.GetAccessControl(filepath, AccessControlSections.Access);
access.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType));
```

(If this general approach works, you might be able to get the access rules out of the `access` object you were creating before and reuse those. They might well stay valid through the delete.)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Get current attributes
var fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath);
```

Delete the file, recreate it and then restore the original permissions using:

```
//Restore the file's original attributes
File.SetAttributes(filePath, fileAttributes);
```

Comment: file attributes don't include access control permissions.

Comment: I checked and double-checked, and this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Ah, ok, you're right.  This code will simply maintain 'ReadOnly' and similar attributes. Not user specific access permissions.